# Web Scraping All Press Products from defense.gov in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to figure out how to do web-scraping on defense.gov, specifically https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products. The problem is that there is a multi-page list implementation with buttons on the bottom to move between "pages" of the list. Ideally, I want to write a piece of code that simply scrapes all of the links and titles of each of the press products so that I can then download each of their contents (using a similar scraping technique) to compile some searchable data.

The search button isn't currently working as far as I can tell, and I also need to search it in a more in-depth way than it allows me to search.

I've tried to scrape it generally, and using BeautifulSoup + requests to get the page does adequately return the first page of elements, but no more than that. I don't know how to use requests properly to send a sort of "click" to the button to advance the next page and then reparse the new HTML.
I've looked into requests.session(), but the only StackOverflow post I could find that was similar to this one was using as an example a website in another language and I had trouble understanding what parts of the code did what as a result.

I also had some issues obtaining the tags associated with each article as well as their date, but I assume I can scrape that once I have the links as they appear at the top of each article's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example how to get titles from multiple pages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products/"
params = {
    "Page": 1
}

for params['Page'] in range(1, 4):  # <--- increase page count here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content, 'html.parser')
    for title in soup.select('[article-title]'):
        print(title['article-title'])
```

Prints:

```
General Officer Assignments
DoD CIO Compliance Confirmation Memo
Readout of Under Secretary of Defense for Policy Dr. Colin Kahl's Meeting With Davor Bozinovic, Deputy Prime Minister of Croatia 
Flag Officer Announcements
Secretary of Defense Lloyd J. Austin III on Australia's Defence Strategic Review
General Officer Announcements
General Officer Announcements
Statement by Secretary of Defense Lloyd J. Austin III on Sudan
Contracts for April 21, 2023
DoD Releases Fiscal Year 2022 Freedom of Navigation Report
DoD Releases Fiscal Year 2022 Freedom of Navigation Report
Secretary of Defense Lloyd J. Austin III and Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff General Mark A. Milley Hold a Post-Ukraine Defense Contact Group Press Conference, Ramstein Air Base, Germany
Navy to Christen Future U.S. Navy Ship Kingsville
Opening Remarks by Secretary of Defense Lloyd J. Austin III at the 11th Ukraine Defense Contact Group (As Delivered)
Secretary of Defense Lloyd J. Austin III and Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff Army Gen. Mark A. Milley Press Conference at Ramstein Air Base in Germany
Contracts for April 20, 2023
DOD General Counsel Delivers Keynote Remarks at U.S. Cyber Command Legal Conference
DOD Produces Climate Assessment Tool, Strengthens Climate Cooperation With Six Allies
Deputy Undersecretary of Defense for Personnel and Readiness Speaks at the Syracuse Service Summit on the Value of Service
Department of Defense Deploys Capabilities in Support of U.S. Embassy Personnel in Sudan
Guantanamo Bay Detainee Transfer Announced
Contracts for April 19, 2023
Biden Administration Announces Additional Security Assistance for Ukraine
Ukraine Fact Sheet – April 19
Media Invitation for May 9 Periodic Review Board
Secretary of Defense Lloyd J. Austin III Joint Press Conference With Swedish Defense Minister Pal Jonson in Stockholm, Sweden
Flag Officer Announcement
Contracts for April 18, 2023
Assistant Secretary of Defense Dr. John F. Plumb Remarks at the Space Foundation's 38th Space Symposium, Colorado Springs, Colorado
DOD General Counsel Remarks at U.S. Cyber Command Legal Conference
```

Comment: What is `soup.select('[article-title]')` doing? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @HenryHarrison `soup.select('[article-title]')` is using beautifulsoup's API for CSS selectors. CSS selector `[article-title]` will select all tags that have `article-title=` parameter.

Comment: Oh, that's really genius

Answer (score 1):

The pages just use a query parameter `Page` to determine which page of releases you want; no button clicking necessary.  Requests makes it simple ([docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)) to supply a query parameter:

```
for page in range(10):  # or use a while loop break when you get no releases
    payload = {'Page': page}
    r = requests.get('https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products/', params=payload)
    # BeautifulSoup here
```

Comment: Oh, interesting! I was wondering though, is there a more general way to handle something like this? Also, where did you see the query parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to 'click' the page button to advance, you could simply scrape each page in turn, in a small loop i.e.:

```
https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products/
https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products/?Page=2
https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products/?Page=3
https://www.defense.gov/News/Press-Products/?Page=4
```

etc

You could also use their RSS feed to make it easier to get the list of pages to scrape:

https://www.defense.gov/DesktopModules/ArticleCS/RSS.ashx?ContentType=9&Site=945&max=100

when you get to  articles that you have already seen, you can stop.